# How to test custom rewrite rules /permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

After much research, I think I can wrap my brain around WP's rewrite system.  I would like to know, though, how to properly test rewrite rules to see if the right rule/tags is being used and the right query vars are being passed.  Is there a way to create a temporary template that supersedes everything in a theme whose sole purpose is to spit out current query_vars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out my favorite [Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) plugin written by @Jan Fabry. It allows you to analyze your rewrite rules and really helps in debugging those rules.